# Why jenkins user is not able to read or write in a directory?

Tags: linux, jenkins, networking, linux-kernel, system-administration

Target directory has a group called "website-handlers" which has perms for Read and Write.
Jenkins user is also assigned to the same group and still its unable to perform in desired manner.[image: img for ref]

I tried playing with perms , but couldnt find what im missing.

Comment: Is that directory mounted via NFS or SMB, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

To have permission to enter a directory you need the execute permission. The output of ls says

```
drwxrw-r-x+
```

which says the owner has execute but the group doesn't. Try

```
chmod g+x www
```

and let me know if it works.

Comment: I deleted that group and added jenkins user to same group as apache2 has which is www-data
Also this time group has rwx